Coldfusion error 500 Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values
I have html sections like below
<cfset formSections = [
    {
        title: "Client Information",
        fields: [
            {label: "Name - First and Last (both)", type: "text", name: "FullName", maxlength: 150},
            {label: "Email Address", type: "text", name: "Email", maxlength: 150},
            {label: "Home Address", type: "textarea", name: "Address1", rows: 4, cols: 50}
        ]
    }
]>

And the formData like
<cfset formData = {"Email" : "imhans@gmail.com", "Fullname" : "Hans M"}>

I am trying to create an html form like below
<cfloop array="#formSections#" index="section">

    <table class="formTable">
        <tr>
            <td height="35" colspan="2" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="##CCCCFF">
                <span style="font-weight: bold">#section.title#</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <cfloop array="#section.fields#" index="field">
            <cfif StructKeyExists(formData, field.name)>
                <tr>
                    <td class="name">#field.label#</td>
                    <td>
                        <cfif field.type IS "text">
                            <input type="#field.type#" name="#field.name#" maxlength="#field.maxlength#"
                                value="#EncodeForHTML(formData[field.name])#">
                        </cfif>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <cfelse>
                <!-- If the item.name does not exist in formData, output the form element without a value -->
                <cfif field.type IS "text">
                    <label for="#field.name#">#field.name#:</label>
                    <input type="#field.type#" name="#field.name#" id="#field.name#" value="" /><br/>
                </cfif>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
    </table>
    <br/>

</cfloop>

But I am getting an error
500 Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.

This error appears in value="#EncodeForHTML(formData[field.name])#"
But no idea how to solve this.. Any help.. thanks in advance
Additional Info
I am creating a form data like below
<cfset keys1 = ["fullname", "address1", "address2", "email", "phone", "username", "password"]>

<cfset keys2 = ["cpdKeys", "cpdLockBox", "cpdRouter", "cpdHomeWarranty"]>
<cfset formData = structNew()>
<cfif StructKeyExists(form, "UserID")>
    <cfset formData['userid'] = form.UserID>

    <cfset userDetailsById = getUserDetails(datasource="#application.dsn#", UserID=form.UserID)>
    <cfset userProfileDetailsById = getClientProfileData(datasource="#application.dsn#", UserID=form.UserID)>

    <cfloop array="#keys1#" index="key">
        <cfset formData[key] = StructKeyExists(userDetailsById, key) ? userDetailsById[key] : "">
    </cfloop>
    <cfloop array="#keys2#" index="key">
        <cfset formData[key] = StructKeyExists(userProfileDetailsById, key) ? userProfileDetailsById[key] : "">
    </cfloop>
<cfelse>
    <cfloop array="#keys1#" index="key">
        <cfset formData[key] = "">
    </cfloop>
    <cfloop array="#keys2#" index="key">
        <cfset formData[key] = "">
    </cfloop>
</cfif>

This is how I am creating the form data...

If formData[field.name] doesn't have the value you expect, the first troubleshooting step is to look at what value it does have, and go from there. Dump it out. Reason as to why it's not the simple value you think it is. Go from there.

Your example code works perfectly fine. I assume you are facing the problem with different formData content?
The error tells you that one of the values in formData is considered "complex", such as structs, arrays or objects. You can catch the bad value by wrapping the throwing line with:
<cfif isSimpleValue(formData[field.name])>
    <input type="#field.type#" name="#field.name#" maxlength="#field.maxlength#" value="#EncodeForHTML(formData[field.name])#">
<cfelse>
    <cfdump label="#field.name# is the culprit" var="#formData[field.name]#" abort>
</cfif>


Thanks for replying... Added additional part on how formData is created
